# Angular ng-repeat is not working for dynamically retrieved data

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular to fetch data using $http and facing a weird issue. In the code snipped below, I have two variables, counters & hardcoded. Both of them have the exact data as can be seen here... the only difference being Counter is retrieved dynamically using an $http call, while HardCoded is declared directly.

```
Counter - [{"name":"Cores Used","percent":"46"},{"name":"Drive Space Used","percent":"66"},{"name":"Memory Used","percent":"30"},{"name":"Network Capacity Used","percent":"52"},{"name":"CPU usage overall","percent":"54"}] 

HardCoded - [{"name":"Cores Used","percent":"59"},{"name":"Drive Space Used","percent":"40"},{"name":"Memory Used","percent":"63"},{"name":"Network Capacity Used","percent":"64"},{"name":"CPU usage overall","percent":"49"}] 

.directive("sfBar", function () {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.counters = attributes["counters"];
        scope.hardcoded = [
            {"name": "Cores Used", "percent": "59"},
            {"name": "Drive Space Used", "percent": "40"},
            {"name": "Memory Used", "percent": "63"},
            {"name": "Network Capacity Used", "percent": "64"},
            {"name": "CPU usage overall", "percent": "49"}
        ];
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "app/common/services/controls/bar.html",
        link: linkFunction,
        scope: {
            counters: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

When I try to do an ng-repeat for hardcoded it works as expected. But when I try the same for counters, it errors out saying...

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=counter%20in%20counters&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:235:172
>       at Object.fn (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:123:30)
>       at n.$digest (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:124:114)
>       at n.$apply (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:127:12)
>       at l (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:81:195)
>       at F (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:85:314)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.C.onload (http://localhost:2000/app/common/vendors/angular/angular.min.js:86:349)

HTML

```
Counter - {{counters}} <br><br>
        HardCoded - {{hardcoded}} <br><br>
        <div ng-repeat="hc in hardcoded">
            {{hc}}
        </div><br><br>
        <div ng-repeat="counter in counters">
            {{counter}}
        </div><br><br>
```

I am struggling and would appreciate any help or pointer.

Comment: Please provide your html .

Comment: there may be duplicate data in your list and ng-repeat don't support dupplicate just `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat`

Comment: Well, as you can see, I have printed the same data as Counter & HardCoded.

Comment: can provide jsfiddle ?